# Batch file with config file (key value pairs) throws errors

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to use a config file to set some variables that will be used by my batch script.

So the config file looks like this:

```
CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME="C:/.../Desktop/jre1.8.0_171"
JAVA_FLAGS="-server -Xmx2048M"
```

In my batch file I have the following:

```
rem load config
if exist cmd.config for /f "delims=" %%A IN (cmd.config) DO (SET "%%A")
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> '""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

A closer look shows that variable `JAVA_FLAGS` is set. I don't get what's failing.

Comment: Just use `SET %%A`.

Comment: @Squashman sweet! thanks. You should add it as the answer :)

Comment: What is the exact path given at `CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME`? does it contain special characters, like `&`, for example?

Comment: Given your example, I'd probably opt for `If Exist "cmd.config" For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A IN ("cmd.config") Do Set "%%A=%%~B"`.

Answer (score 0):

My best practice has always been not to assign surrounding quotes to variables. Essentially that is why you got the error you did. You assigned quotes to the variables and then surrounded the use of those variables with quotes.  So it ends up seeing your variable as `""C:/.../Desktop/jre1.8.0_171""`.  With you existing code you can just remove the quotes around the `%%A`but my best practice has always been to NOT assign quotes to variables but do use them when they are needed with another command.

Config

```
CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME=C:/.../Desktop/jre1.8.0_171
JAVA_FLAGS=-server -Xmx2048M
```

BATCH

```
rem load config
if exist cmd.config for /f "eol=# delims=" %%A IN (cmd.config) DO (SET "%%A")
```

Comment: I get the quote thing, however, i need to config to be compatible with shell (linux), so I need the variable value between quotes (I then “import” the config in my sh script with `.`).

Comment: @FedeE. I looked back at some of the bash scripts I wrote years ago and I had no problems not assigning surrounding quotes to the value of a variable.

Comment: I actually added them after facing problems with spaces witin the variable values. Like in the flahs variable.

Comment: @FedeE. Like I said in my previous comments, you use the quotes when they are needed with another command to protect spaces and special characters.